# mysqli_insert_id returning 0

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have to use a reference to a record in another table (FK). The record in the other table may or not exist, so I can either use its ID or insert a new one and then use its ID.

I have the following code:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","test","db_site");

// get existing levels
$levelIdSQL = "SELECT idlevel from levels where levelstring = $level";
$levels = mysqli_query($con, $levelIdSQL);      

$levelID = -1;
if ($levels['num_rows'] > 0) {
    echo "<br><br>some results<br><br>";
    // we already have a level, use its id when updating
    $row = $levels->fetch_assoc();
    $levelID = $row['idlevel'];
} else {
    // we must insert this string in the levels table, then use its id
    echo "<br>running query: " . "INSERT INTO `db_site`.`levels` ('levelstring') values ('$level');"; 
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    } else {
        echo "<br><br>connected OK<br><br>";
    }       
    $rez = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `db_site`.`levels` ('levelstring') values ('$level');");
    $levelID =  mysqli_insert_id($con);                 
}
echo "<br><br>LEVEL ID: " . $levelID;
```

My **levels** table has an autoinc "idlevel" field and running the same SQL with MySQL Workbench/command line interface inserts the record just fine. However, **mysqli_insert_id** returns 0 and no records are inserted.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: after jterry's suggestion, I called die() and it returned: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''levelstring')". So I changed this:

```
$rez = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `db_site`.`levels` ('levelstring') values ('$level');");
```

into this:

```
$rez = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `db_site`.`levels` (levelstring) values ('$level');");
```

Everything is ok now.

Comment: You're connecting twice to the database. The insert_id() functions work on a per-connection basis.

Comment: I edited my code and question, no luck.

Comment: Are you sure your query actually works out? You're not checking what `$rez` contains. Also, does your table have an auto-increment identifier field? That is required to get a value back

Comment: My table does have an auto-inc field (the insert works fine in Mysql Workspace for example). $rez contains nothing, it's empty.

Comment: If you add `if(false === $rez) die(mysqli_error($con));` after running your query, does the script die with an error?

Comment: jterry: very useful command, I'll edit my question. Please add an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this , you should use backticks around column name not quotes.

```
$rez = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `db_site`.`levels` ( `levelstring`) 
                           VALUES ('$level') ");
```